# jquery (e) function parameter meaning

Tags: jquery

I am using Dreamweaver for jQuery coding and it automatically completes the initial jquery selection as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

});
```

What does the "e" mean in the function definition and what is the official documentation of this parameter? A link would be helpful to official documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case `e` refers to jQuery object itself and is used for preventing conflict with other libraries that use `$`. The first parameter of `ready` handler refers to the jQuery object. In this case using `e` as a reference to jQuery is ***not*** a good decision and if DreamWeaver wrongfully chooses/passes `e`, you should change it yourself.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('query').foo();
});
```

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

But generally `e` is used as an alias for `event` object in other cases.

```
$('element').on('event', function(e) {
   var eventObject = e;
});
```